# passing an object in the attribute of a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, mbunit

how could i pass an object in my unit test?
here's my code:

```
    [Test]          
    [Row( "test",5,new CustomField())]      
    public void Test_Constructor(string type, int number, CustomField customField)
    {
       .....
    }
```

it returns an error: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a factory:

http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit:data-driven_testing:factory

Comment: that's nice but actually, my row attribute is in a format like this:
[Row("string",5,new Class1()))]. I cant implement a factory in my test.

Comment: You can return an array from the factory, look at the "complex factory" example.