# passing object in the Row attribute of a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, mbunit, gallio

i am trying to pass an object alongside with other parameters in the Row attribute of a unit test.

```
    [Row("Test1", new CustomField(), 3)]  // parameters MUST be string, object and int    
    public void Test_Constructor(string testType, CustomField customField, int num)
    {
       .....
    }
```

but this will return an error:

```
 An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.
```

how can i do this....

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing an object in the attribute of a unit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327259/passing-an-object-in-the-attribute-of-a-unit-test)

Comment: sorry, i thought that question didnt submit because my internet connection failed when i submitted that question through my mobile phone